# jQuery scrollTop offset not scrolling to target element on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been trying to write a jQuery code for a form so that when a user selects one radio button, the page automatically scrolls to the next question wrapped by a class of `frm_opt_container`

This is the HTML structure of my page:

```
<div class="frm_opt_container">
  <div class="frm_radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="frm_radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio">
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="frm_radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery I've written:

```
//Scroll Function
var option = document.querySelectorAll('label');
for (var i = 0;; i++) {
  option[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ele = $(this).parents('.frm_opt_container');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }, 200);
  });
}
```

**The problem:** The code works fine on desktop but it scrolls just a little on mobile when there are two many options to a question (I've displayed them as block on mobile).

Here's a [reference link](https://webdcouple.ikowaguy.com/loan-application/) to the page containing just the form. You can use the first question with the radio buttons to test on mobile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".frm_radio input").on('change', function() {

        var selector = $(this).closest('div').next();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Try this jQuery code

Comment: Thank you for making the code much shorter than before. Unfortunately, the problem is still isn't solved on mobile. I'm starting to wonder whether there is some restriction to the amount by which scrolling is allowed by scrollTop.

Comment: Edit: your code has managed to scroll to the question but all the options of the question are below the fold. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking to do?

Once a radio button is changed/clicked animate to the next `.frm_form_fields` by targeting `$(this).parents(".frm_form_fields").next()`: Find the input's `.frm_form_fields` parent and choose the next one on the DOM.

```js
$(".frm_radio input").change(function () {
  const $target = $(this).parents(".frm_form_fields").next();

  if ($target.length < 1) {
    return;
  }

  $("html, body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    },
    1000
  );
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding-bottom: 600px;
}

.frm_radio {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: cadetblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="frm_form_fields active">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="frm_field_8_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_required_field frm_top_container hear frm_two_col">
        <div id="field_e41hw_label" class="frm_primary_label">How did you hear about us?
        </div>
        <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_e41hw_label" role="group">
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-0">
            <label for="field_e41hw-0">
              <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-0" value="Google / Youtube" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false">Google / Youtube
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-1">
            <label for="field_e41hw-1">
              <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-1" value="Facebook / Instagram" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false">Facebook / Instagram
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="frm_form_fields">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="frm_field_8_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_required_field frm_top_container hear frm_two_col">
        <div id="field_e41hw_label" class="frm_primary_label">How did you hear about us?
          <span class="frm_required" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_e41hw_label" role="group">
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-2"><label for="field_e41hw-2"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-2" value="Yahoo / Bing" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> Yahoo / Bing</label></div>
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-3"><label for="field_e41hw-3"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-3" value="Email" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> Email</label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="frm_form_fields">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="frm_field_8_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_required_field frm_top_container hear frm_two_col">
        <div id="field_e41hw_label" class="frm_primary_label">How did you hear about us?
          <span class="frm_required" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_e41hw_label" role="group">

          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-4"><label for="field_e41hw-4"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-4" value="ATM machine" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> ATM machine</label></div>
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-5"><label for="field_e41hw-5"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-5" value="Another Client" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> Another Client</label></div>
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-6"><label for="field_e41hw-6"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-6" value="ATM" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> ATM</label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="frm_form_fields">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="frm_field_8_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_required_field frm_top_container hear frm_two_col">
        <div id="field_e41hw_label" class="frm_primary_label">How did you hear about us?
          <span class="frm_required" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_e41hw_label" role="group">
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-7"><label for="field_e41hw-7"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-7" value="Billboard" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> Billboard</label></div>
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-8"><label for="field_e41hw-8"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-8" value="Friend / family" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> Friend / family</label></div>
          <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_8-9"><label for="field_e41hw-9"> <input type="radio" name="item_meta[8]" id="field_e41hw-9" value="I’m a past client" data-reqmsg="This field cannot be blank." data-invmsg="How did you hear about us? is invalid" aria-invalid="false"> I’m a past client</label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

</div> <!-- End of container for all radio buttons -->
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. Your code implies scrolling to the closest ".frm_radio" class which is nothing but just another radio button class. I intend for the page to scroll to the next question which has the class ".frm_opt_container".

Comment: Ah I didn’t understand the intended behavior. I can certainly help you with that code when I’m back at my computer in a few hours.  Very doable!

Comment: Tailored the code for your desired behavior. Is this what you're looking for?